# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined with Angular's http.get

Tags: angularjs

For a test I have the following code added to my test.ts, which I included in the main.ts.

```
var http:Http;
let headers = new Headers();
headers.set('Accept', 'text/json');
let url = 'http://localhost:8080/usersdto';

http.get(url, { headers})
  .subscribe(resp => showResponse(resp), err => showResponse(err));
```

So this is no Class, just typescript. I get the error pointing to line 'http.get' (showResponse exists as function):

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined
```

Why do I get this Error and how do I define the http object correctly ?

Answer (score 1):

First you need to import `HttpClient` from `@angular/common/http`. Then you define the http object by injecting it into the constructor of the class you want to use it in.

All of what you need and best practices are explained in [this example](https://investmentnovel.com/angular-6-http-get-example/).

Hope that helps.

Comment: So I can't do it like I did for testing only ?

Comment: HttpClient is available as an injectable class, so there's no way to use it without injecting it.